# In what order does a .gitlab-ci.yml file execute its stages?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml

New to GitLab and Yaml here. I have the following code in my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
variables:
    SERVICE_NAME: exchange-rates-app

stages:
    - build
    - deploy
    
.deploy: &deploy
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Deploying"
build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building"
    <<: *deploy
```

Upon checking the build, only `Deploying` was echoed. If my understanding is correct, since Build is the first step of the stages followed by Deploy, it should echo "Building" first, and then "Deploying" since `<<: *deploy` is called inside build. Why is it only echoing `Deploying`?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `<<: *deploy` you are overwriting the contents of `build.script`. You should make a separate deploy job and it will automatically depend on the build one:

```
variables:
    SERVICE_NAME: exchange-rates-app

stages:
    - build
    - deploy

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building"

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Deploying"
```